# Stokes theorem: $ \vec{v} = (xz, -y, x^2y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Evaluate

$$ \iint_S \nabla \times \vec{v} . \vec{N} dS$$

where $\vec{v} = (xz, -y, x^2y)$ and S consists of the 5 faces, not on xy plane, of the cube$ [0,2] \times [0,2] \times [0,2] $ and $ \vec{N}$ points to the exterior of the surface

**My attempt**: In this case, we can apply the Stokes theorem over the surface. But note that the border orientation, given the normal orientation, is the following

[image]

Then, the integral of the curl will be the integral pf $\vec{v}$ over the border of the square $[0,2] \times [0,2]$ in the xy plane. Evaluating this integral, I got 0, but the answer is $-4$. Can someone check my calculus?
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can actally use Stokes again to get to the integral of $\nabla \times v . N $ over the bottom surface of the cube. But for this I get $0$ as well....

Comment: I was going to make an edit and say the same... (just considering the surface as the square in xy, right?) Thanks, by the way

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would work through it and see where we agree.

Firstly $\nabla\times v=(\frac{d}{dy}(x^2y)-\frac{d}{dz}(-y),\frac{d}{dz}(xz)-\frac{d}{dx}(x^2y),\frac{d}{dx}(-y)-\frac{d}{dy}(xz))=(x^2,x-2xy,0)$

We have 5 normals corresponding to the 5 faces of the surface, so in each case we have:

$n=(0,0,1), \nabla\times v\cdot n=0$

$n=(-1,0,0), \nabla\times v\cdot n=-x^2=-1$

$n=(1,0,0), \nabla\times v\cdot n=x^2=1$

$n=(0,-1,0), \nabla\times v\cdot n=2xy-x=-3$

$n=(0,1,0), \nabla\times v\cdot n=x-2xy=-x$

We can see that the sum of the first three integrals would be zero by symmetry.

but $\iint_{[0,2]\times[0,2]}-3x-x\,dx\,dz=(-2x^2|_0^2)(z|_0^2)=-16$

this differs by a scale of 4 from the answer given.